# Remove spaces between characters of output Batch file

Tags: batch-file, output, wmic, sfc

I have a batch file that outputs the Wi-Fi adapter MAC address to a text file using the command `wmic nic where "name like '%%802%%'" get name,macaddress` and there are spaces between characters. I get the same thing for `sfc /scannow` in a batch file.

The output of the `wmic` command is:

```
Hostname: SOME-COMPUTER
  A C A d d r e s s                   N a m e
 3 4 : F 6 : B 3 : J 3 : 6 3 : 1 3     B r o a d c o m   8 0 2 . 1 1 n   N e t w o r k   A d a p t e r
```

The snippet of output of the `sfc` scan is:

```
n   3 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   3 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   4 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   5 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 2 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 3 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 4 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 5 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 6 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 7 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 8 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   6 9 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   7 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   7 0 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   7 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   7 1 %   c o m p l e t e . V e r i f i c a t i o n   7 1 %   c o m p l e t e .        V   e   r   i   f   i   c   a   t   i   o   n       7   2   %
```

When I run these commands from cmd.exe, the output looks like this:

```
MACAddress         Name
34:F2:B3:A1:83:33  Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
```

I would use PowerShell normally, but that is not what I need here. I would like the output to look like this in the output file.

The output doesn't seem to care if I use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` `endlocal`, as the output is the same.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

I created a blank Unicode file ( I have Windows 10 ), and copied it to a new file I used for the output file. Now, the spaces are gone, but for whatever reason, the variable created for the hostname outputs what appears to be Chinese characters:

```
潈瑳慮敭›䕄䭓佔ⵐ䩒䵔剄⁓਍MACAddress         Name                              
34:F2:B3:A1:83:33  Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
```

The `hostname` command was used as follows:

```
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%i in ('hostname') do (
    set "nameHost=%%i"
)
```

Then, I changed `tokens=*` to `tokens=2` and all of the characters were Chinese. Anyway, a work-around was to add the hostname to the filename instead, which resolves this issue. However, it would be ideal to learn how to have both ANSI and Unicode strings in the same file, without the spaces.

I saw a C++ article about this and the answer was to change the code; therefore, if that it true, I don't have the code for `sfc` or `wmic`, so am I SOL there, or is there a way to have both ANSI and Unicode strings in the same file without the spaces between each character?

Comment: The issue is likely that you are appending the unicode, _(UTF-16 LE, BOM)_, output from `WMIC` to a file already created as ANSI. It may therefore be a simple case of changing the order such that you output the unicode stuff first.

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic nic where "name like '%%802%%'" get name,macaddress|more
```

should provide you with an ANSI version - the problem there is Unicode-output from `WMIC`.